# Flutter SoundPool play sound issue

Tags: android, flutter, soundpool

I am struggling playing sounds with SoundPool on Flutter.
I have read/Googled about the dreaded message "AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by server; frameCount 0 -> 48000"

So far, here are the steps I have taken :

- Image running in emulator is Pixel 3A
- Files are wav, with a size of 90K, they last 1 second each, they are 48K sampled (ffmprobe says :Duration: 00:00:01.00, bitrate: 768 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 768 kb/s)
- I have pre-loaded then during app startup with Asset, follows code (within a foreach):

```
     var content = await _bundle.load(notePath);
     sounds[notePath] = content;
     newNote.soundId = await _pool.load(content);
     new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: (2000)), () => print("loaded $notePath"));
```

I have put a duration, else some (randomly) sounds were not loaded (I have 72 sounds to load).
When I need to play the sound (upon tap on the screen), I simply do a

```
_pool.stop(1);
_pool.play(noteToPlay.soundId);
```

Which creates some crackle (one guy proposed instead to always play a sound at volume 0 to avoid this, but this will drain the battery).

Now the problem :
The message appears in the console, but I could live with it if there were not the following issue : 
Randomly, some sounds are not played, the taps are simply ignored. The app never crashes. If I remove the soundPool.play call, then everything is ok (corresponding file is found, tap is handled...), so I gather that soundPool gets lost during one of the Future playback. Player can tap very quickly, but even If I go slow, it still fails.

SoundPool is instanciated like this :

```
class NoteService {
  final Soundpool _pool = Soundpool(streamType: StreamType.notification);
[snip class definition]
```

Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing streamType in SoundPool's constructor to StreamType.alarm

```
pool = Soundpool(streamType: StreamType.alarm);
```